# C# - proxy HTTPWebRequest error

Tags: c#, proxy

I am getting some errors today when i had updated my APP with proxy to prevent DDOS Protection from blocking it code:

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();
proxy.address = "http://{ip}:{port}";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site);
request.Proxy = proxy;
```

Errors:

> 'System.Net.WebProxy' does not contain a definition for 'address' and
>   no extension method 'address' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Net.WebProxy' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, there is no `address` property on `WebProxy`. You can either change it to `Address` (note the casing difference), or use the constructor that takes the address (`new WebProxy("http://{ip}:{port}")`).